# Iteration copies more than one char

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, assign

The problem seems with this function:

```
void CatString(const char* srcStr, char** destStr, size_t* destCap) {

    size_t destLen = strlen(*destStr);
    unsigned int posDest = destLen;
    int posSrc = 0;

    while(srcStr[posSrc] != '\0') {
        if( (destLen + 1) > *destCap )
            DoubleString(destStr, destCap);

        (*destStr)[posDest] = srcStr[posSrc];
        posDest++;
        posSrc++;
        destLen++;
    }
}
```

The function is supposed to concatenate source string into destination string. If destination string is not big enough, its size is doubled using `DoubleString()`.

Let's say `srcStr` is `Circles identical, overlap:` and `destStr` is empty.

Debugging, I found out that at iteration 21 (`posSrc == 22`) `srcStr` is `Circles identical, over`. AT THE NEXT ITERATION a problem occurs:

`(*destStr)[posDest] = srcStr[posSrc];` does the unexpected -

`srcStr` changes from `Circles identical, over` to `Circles identical, overlerlap:`. Next step works as I expected and string becomes `Circles identical, overlarlap:` and so on, until string becomes `Circles identical, overlap: p:`. So without unexpected iteration 22, the program behaves normally. My previous usages also didn't show any signs of errors.

**So what made the assignment at step 22 copy more than one char?**

More of the code for context [**here**](https://pastebin.com/B33idrM4).

EDIT: Null-terminating my result actually seems to fixed the issue, program `assert`s correctly now and `valgrind` is also satisfied.

Comment: You can't look at your strings in the debugger while they are still a work in progress, because they are not null terminated. Moreover, you never null-terminate the result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Holy molly, the null-termination of the result was what caused the error. I guess the string wasn't `free`d properly so it caused some issues onwards?

Comment: Freeing the string is independent of null termination. Without null termination everything will display your string incorrectly, including the debugger. If you want to see the string in the debugger as the copy is happening, fill the memory with zeros after allocation.

Answer (score 1):

if the *destStr was malloc-ed:

```
int CatString(const char* srcStr, char** destStr) 
{
    int result = 0;
    char * tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(*destStr) + strlen(srcStr) + 1));

    if (tmp == NULL) result = -1;
    if (!result)
    {
        strcpy(tmp, destStr);
        strcat(tmp, srcStr);
        free(*destStr);
        *destStr = tmp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

or

```
int CatString(const char* srcStr, char** destStr, size_t destCap) 
{
    int result = 0;
    size_t newStrlen = strlen(*destStr) + strlen(srcStr);

    newStrlen = newStrlen > destCap ? destCap : newStrlen;

    char * tmp = malloc(newStrlen + 1);

    if (tmp == NULL) result = -1;
    if (!result)
    {
        strcpy(tmp, *destStr);
        strncat(tmp, srcStr, newStrlen - strlen(*destStr));
        tmp[newStrlen] = '\0';
        free(*destStr);
        *destStr = tmp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is strange and difficult to analyse. If you get to this point it is better to reconsider the algorithm.

Comment: Your code is definitely cleaner and doesn't need an additional `DoubleString()` function. Anyway, it looks like not null-terminating my result-string was what caused the issue.